Search in multiple Power Automate Flows
I have multiple Power Automate Flows in an environment. I would like to find a flow that writes a row to a data verse table. We have multiple flows in the environment more than 100. What is the most efficient way to find the flow?
We tried to use xrmtoolbox, but it only allows to search in flow triggers, not in actions.

Export them all and use VS code over the files.

I cant export them, they are in a managed solution

What about the unmanaged solution?

We only have a managed solution

Do you have Power Automate Insights enabled? you may be able to filter flows based on some metrics so you can check which flows are interacting with Dataverse tables based on execution data.
It is either you do it manually access details about all flows in your environment in Power Platform Admin Center and you check under Solutions and select your Managed Solution and manually search for the "Dataverse" connector or any action that indicates it writes to Dataverse.
Or maybe PowerShell Cmdlets can help (Get-AdminFlow)
